# Flex Error when shutting down Tomcat Apache

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat

I'm getting the following error in my Tomcat Console when shutting down Apache.

```
SEVERE: The web application [/xxxxxx] created a ThreadLocal with key of 
type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@185ad79]) and a value of 
type [flex.messaging.client.FlexClient] (value [flex.messaging.client.FlexClient@1401d28]) 
but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely 
to create a memory leak.
```

I'm using Flex 3.6A with Tomcat Apache 6.0.39.

I have a feeling that I'm not shutting down Flex gracefully in my ServletContextListener, but I can't find the command to do so.